# router.push after axios Post , Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I try a redirect after a post request is made, and I tried different things but nothing worked till now.

```
self.$router.push('/record')
Vue.$router.push('/record')
this.$router.push({ name: 'Record' })
```

**Here is the updated code. with axios form component, app.js and main.js**

```
axios.delete('/record/' + this.id)
.then((response) => {
    this.$router.push('/record')
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    //
});
```

**In my app.js**

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import router from "./router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Record from './components/AddPerson';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/record",
        name: "Record",
        component: Record,
    },
];


const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Is there a console error?  Can you show your router definitions?

Comment: Show us your axios code.

Comment: I updated the post, and I have no errors in console.

Comment: There's an extra `});` underneath the `push`

Answer (score 0):

Do you trying to redirect to the same route?

The Vue cache the components, because this is more fast.

If this is your problem, you must do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
};
</script>
```

```js
axios
  .delete(`/record/${this.id}`)
  .then(response => {
    this.$router.push({
      name: 'Record',
      query: { x: new Date().toISOString() },
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    //
  });
```